# Show that there are infinitely many such matrices $B$ for which $AB = A$ holds.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\3 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$ Show that there are infinitely many such matrices $B$ for which
$AB = A$ holds.

The idea that I thought is that in order $AB = A$ holds B must be identity matrix.However the answer is different.How can I proof it?

Comment: $B$ only has to be the identity if $A$ is invertible. But $A$ here is not invertible since its determinant is zero,

Comment: correct @coffeemath I forget that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a super explicit demonstration.

Let $$B=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $AB = A$ implies the following system of equations

$$a + 2c = 1$$ $$b +2 d = 2$$ $$a + 2c = 1$$ $$b + 2d = 2$$  by comparing each component and simplifying.

You can see that we therefore have $a + 2c = 1$ and $b+2d = 2$. This system is under-prescribed ($4$ variables, $2$ linearly independent equations) so there is not a unique solution for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$

Hence there are infinitely many matrices $B$ that satisfy the relation $AB = A$, with the elements of $B$ satisfying $a + 2c = 1$ and $b+2d=2$.

Comment: Best Answer! Clear now

Answer (score 3):

One approach is as follows: note that
$$
AB = A \implies AB - AI = 0 \implies A(B - I) = 0
$$
Now, let $M = B - I$. We can see that if $M_1,M_2$ are the columns of $M$, then
$$
AM = A \pmatrix{M_1 & M_2} = \pmatrix{AM_1 & AM_{2}}.
$$
In other words, $M$ satisfies the requirement of $AM = 0$ whenever the columns of $M$ are solutions to $Ax = 0$.

Comment: $AB=A$ not to $ B $

Comment: @subhanceo that was a typo, see my latest edit

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether my solution is the best but I'll show it. So I set up a matrix equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4\\
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4\\
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now I calculated first multiplication and get:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4\\
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2a + 4c & 2b + 4d\\
3a + 6c & 3b + 6d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now set system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
2a+4c = 2\\
3a+6c = 3
\end{cases}
$$
and as we can see, this system has infinite numbers of solutions. Similarly we can do with $b,d$ variables.